# Package main is not acceptable in test file golang

Tags: go, grpc

I'm trying to create a test file to my create function file in golang with gRPC. My directory body is:

```
src
  >server
    > create_coin_test.go
    > create_coin.go
    >main.go
```

"main.go" file is where I set up my server and its package is "main"

```
package main

// import (...)

// var collection *mongo.Collection
// var addr string = "0.0.0.0:50051"

// rest of code...
```

My "create_coin.go" has the same package main and it's ok.

The problem is with **create_coin_test.go**. I'm receiving this error about using package main

```
No packages found for open file /home/user/projects/currency_coin/src/server/create_coin_test.go: <nil>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen my error happened with a conflicting in go.mod file.
My error there was:

```
internal error: go list gives conflicting information for package
```

I used command `go mod tidy` and for this case resolved.